# What is the easiest way to get the url a link redirects to?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have a number of urls that redirect to other ones and I would like to find the address of the links they redirect to. For example,

`https://stlouisfed.org/fomcspeak/thomas-barkin/2019/04/apr-speech-a-practitioners-perspective-on-the-productivity-slowdown`

redirects to

`https://www.richmondfed.org/press_room/speeches/thomas_i_barkin/2019/barkin_speech_20190404`

I tried using the `requests` library like so:

```
import requests

url = "https://stlouisfed.org/fomcspeak/thomas-barkin/2019/04/apr-speech-a-practitioners-perspective-on-the-productivity-slowdown"

def get_redirected_url(url: str) -> str:
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.url

get_redirected_url(url)
```

But I'm running getting the error below. Any idea what might be going wrong?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py in wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname)
    487             try:
--> 488                 cnx.do_handshake()
    489             except OpenSSL.SSL.WantReadError:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py in do_handshake(self)
   1933 
-> 1934         :param addr: A remove address
   1935         :return: What the socket's connect_ex method returns

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py in _raise_ssl_error(self, ssl, result)
   1670 
-> 1671     def set_tlsext_host_name(self, name):
   1672         """

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py in exception_from_error_queue(exception_type)
     53                 text(lib.ERR_reason_error_string(error)),
---> 54             )
     55         )

Error: [('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

SSLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    669             # Make the request on the httplib connection object.
--> 670             httplib_response = self._make_request(
    671                 conn,

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    380         try:
--> 381             self._validate_conn(conn)
    382         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError) as e:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _validate_conn(self, conn)
    977         if not getattr(conn, "sock", None):  # AppEngine might not have  `.sock`
--> 978             conn.connect()
    979 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py in connect(self)
    361 
--> 362         self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
    363             sock=conn,

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py in ssl_wrap_socket(sock, keyfile, certfile, cert_reqs, ca_certs, server_hostname, ssl_version, ciphers, ssl_context, ca_cert_dir, key_password, ca_cert_data)
    385         if HAS_SNI and server_hostname is not None:
--> 386             return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
    387 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py in wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname)
    493             except OpenSSL.SSL.Error as e:
--> 494                 raise ssl.SSLError("bad handshake: %r" % e)
    495             break

SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])",)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    438             if not chunked:
--> 439                 resp = conn.urlopen(
    440                     method=request.method,

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    725 
--> 726             retries = retries.increment(
    727                 method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    445         if new_retry.is_exhausted():
--> 446             raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
    447 

MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='stlouisfed.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /fomcspeak/thomas-barkin/2019/04/apr-speech-a-practitioners-perspective-on-the-productivity-slowdown (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

SSLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-126-5a66b7870cb5> in <module>
----> 1 get_redirected_url(url)

<ipython-input-125-d2cc1a52d8fa> in get_redirected_url(url)
      1 def get_redirected_url(url: str) -> str:
      2 #     url = urljoin("https://stlouisfed.org/", url)
----> 3     r = requests.get(url, timeout=10)
      4     return r.url
      5 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py in get(url, params, **kwargs)
     73 
     74     kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
---> 75     return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
     76 
     77 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     58     # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
     59     with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 60         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     61 
     62 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    531         }
    532         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 533         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    534 
    535         return resp

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    644 
    645         # Send the request
--> 646         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    647 
    648         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    512             if isinstance(e.reason, _SSLError):
    513                 # This branch is for urllib3 v1.22 and later.
--> 514                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    515 
    516             raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)

SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='stlouisfed.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /fomcspeak/thomas-barkin/2019/04/apr-speech-a-practitioners-perspective-on-the-productivity-slowdown (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))
```

Comment: Your machine being unable to verify the stlouisfed.org certificate is completely unrelated to the problem of finding the redirect Location

Comment: Did you attempt to read and understand the error message? In your own words, what do you think it is trying to tell you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced your issue with the following code:

```py
import requests
url = "https://stlouisfed.org/fomcspeak/thomas-barkin/2019/04/apr-speech-a-practitioners-perspective-on-the-productivity-slowdown"
def get_redirected_url(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.url
get_redirected_url(url)
```

And the root cause is the server stlouisfed.org doesn't provide the right certificate chain, the L1K intermediate certificate is missing. You can confirm it by checking https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=https://stlouisfed.org/

To solve/workaround it on your side (client-side), I found 2 options:

1. you can change url = "https://stlouisfed.org/fomcspeak/thomas-barkin/2019/04/apr-speech-a-practitioners-perspective-on-the-productivity-slowdown"
   to
   url = "https://**www**.stlouisfed.org/fomcspeak/thomas-barkin/2019/04/apr-speech-a-practitioners-perspective-on-the-productivity-slowdown"
   as the [www.stlouisfed.org](http://www.stlouisfed.org) certificate chain is valid.
2. you can add the missing certificate L1K into your certificate trust file:
   first, download the certificate from
   https://tls-observatory.services.mozilla.com/static/certsplainer.html?id=1439
   2nd, update your certificate trust file, in my centos 7, I need to
   add a new file called l1k.pem into /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors with the content mentioned in step1, and then run command update-ca-trust; then confirm the certificate is added in file /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt.

With either option, the redirected URL can be returned.

Comment: This may fix the issue of connecting to the site, but OP is asking a question unrelated to the error. It should not be answered until we are all on the same page. If the problem is simply with making the connection, then the question is ill posed. If the problem with getting the redirected URL persists, then it should be re-asked with updated information - an example that reproduces *the problem being asked about*, not just any error.

Comment: after changing like I mentioned, the redirected URL is returned. Thanks for your comments.